# Export from SAS EG to sharepoint

Tags: sas, export-to-csv

I can't figure this out! :

Is it possible to export from SAS enterprise guide to a sharepoint webpage with code or point and click solution?

If yes, how?

- In this case I want to export a csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with SAS to write to Sharepoint.

The main way you'd do this is to map the Sharepoint directory to a virtual directory locally using WebDAV. If you can do that, SAS can write to it as any other folder.  I've done this before; it's not all that easy to get the configuration right, but with some help from your SharePoint admin you can probably do this (if your SAS server is on a Windows box).

9.4 also created the `WebDAV filename` access method (see [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/68024/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0l1vivxo238din1jt3sip83eugu.htm)) which should work on non-Windows boxes.  This will ultimately be fundamentally similar to the first method (both use WebDAV).

Finally, if you license SAS Visual Analytics, you can use the SAS WebParts tool to connect directly with a Sharepoint server to populate a custom WebPart. See the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/wbptswssug/67335/HTML/default/viewer.htm#wbptswssugwhatsnew61.htm) for more information.